# Cross Platform Terminal/SCP app

Tags: networking, command-line, windows-7

I am doing more network device management at work, (mainly cisco and juniper) and need tools to telnet/ssh and SCP to manage the devices. I am comfortable with the gnome terminal, but wouldn't mind having a tool that makes it easy to "bookmark" hosts, and even drag and drop scp copying would be helpful.  I use Putty at the moment in windows, (and WinSCP for copying files) but was wondering if there was a better, or more integrated cross platform tool. (work machines have windows 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PuTTY really is the de facto cross-platform telnet/SSH application. I am having trouble identifying exactly what you're looking for, but of the following criteria:

1. Free
2. Supports Windows and Linux
3. GUI (bookmarking and drag and drop)

PuTTY, as far as I am aware, is the only piece of software that satisfies all constraints. WinSCP is Windows-only and all other clients with which I am familiar are either commercially licensed or text-based. FileZilla *may* support SSH, I have not tested this personally but potentially it could be a more robust file manager than PuTTY or WinSCP.

Also, for what it's worth, GNOME/Nautilus supports browsing of SSH shares from "Places > Connect to Server..." It supports bookmarks and (obviously) drag and drop.

Sources: [This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_clients) and my own experience with various SSH clients.

Answer (score 0):

i use **gftp** as my ftp client. I havent tried it personally but i think there is a way to make gftp work with scp /ssh.

have a look here.

http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/Using_gFTP_with_ssh_sftp.html

Or you can use **secpanel.**

http://themediahost.de/secpanel/

Though none better than putty for ssh/telnet which incidentally is Cross Platform